# Use existing Win7 code base in Windows 8 App

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows

In my company we have an existing product that runs on Windows 7 and communicates with our web services.

We wish to make a Windows 8 tablet version of our product, and my first thought was:
"Hey, its just a new Windows version, so we can probably use our existing model, data access and business layer logic projects, and just focus on making a new UI layer"

But I fear that this is not the case, or am I wrong? 
I tried opening our VS2010 solution file in VS2012 Express, but received an error "This edition of Visual Studio only supports Windows Store apps".

So, my naive hope now is: Can anyone tell me the easiest way to make our existing code work in a Windows 8 App?

EDIT:
The code is .NET C#, and my thought was that I just wanted to make a Windows 8 app so that the product had a tablet/touch friendly interface.

Comment: But you want to make Metro style app or desktop app? What technology you used in Windows 7 app?

Comment: For Enterprises: This might be an interesting read (dev-oriented) http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-apps-whats-enterprise-to-do.html

Answer (score 1):

In general, you'll make a new UI using XAML, reuse a lot of your existing code, and change the data access to use SQLite.

[VS2012 Express Edition](http://aka.ms/downloadvs2012) is for making Windows Store apps.  By "Windows Store" app, I mean an app which uses the WinRT APIs.  Depending on your code, making a Windows Store version of your app can be straightforward.

If you need other features, you might need [a different version of Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare).  You definitely need to be on 2012 though.  You can't build a Windows Store application with Visual Studio 2010.  I think you know this already though.

If your existing .NET app uses WPF for the UI, you can reuse a lot of your XAML knowledge for the Windows 8 port.  It's not as simple as recompiling, but it should be straightforward.

SQL CE is currently not an option for Windows Store applications.  Instead, consider using [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/).

Take a look at a post on MSDN called [.NET for Windows Store apps - supported APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx).  Some APIs you may be familiar with have been moved to WinRT.  Sometimes porting is as simple as changing namespaces.

You mention that you also write to the C: drive.  There's a [sample on MSDN on how to read and write files](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597).

Comment: It's .NET and we're using a SQL CE for data, and some storage on C: as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at those links :)

Answer (score 0):

So You need to build a new Metro Style Interface.

Wen You built interface just copy the Logic of your old application.

You can open old application in old VS 2010 and **copy code line by line**.

You can't convert old Windows app to Metro Style App.

Comment: This is really a blow to the face. Our model, database and logic layers all contain stuff that isn't in the metro .NET, so as far as I can tell we can't easily re-use our existing libraries as references :(